# Bind to dynamically added content WITHOUT jquery?

Tags: javascript

If I'm adding a form to my page dynamically (whether through AJAX or other JS), how can I add event listeners to those elements on pageload before they exist?

I know with jquery it's fairly easy to bind to a parent element, something like this:

```
$(document).on('blur', 'input', function() {...})
```

but I'm unclear on how to do this with vanilla JS as `addEventListener` must be applied directly to the element itself and can't specify the parent element for which the event should propagate? (I think, right..?)

Comment: Well, `$(document).on(...)` binds the event to `document`. You'd do the same. All you have to do manually in the event handler is to check whether the event originates from an `input` element.

Comment: You can do it in a similar way. You attach the listener to the `document` and check if the clicked target is the one you want and perform your action from there.

Comment: In this example I'm specifically looking for input blur, so if I `addEventListener` to document for the 'blur' event, won't that never fire? I need to specifically say, essentially, if an input within the document blurs, not the document itself.

Comment: Thats how delegation works. Will work the same for the `blur` event.

Comment: The problem is `focus` and `blur` don't bubble in some browsers. jQuery patches this in.

Comment: There's an answer in the duplicate question that shows how to do it with pure Javascript.

Comment: Good point @NiettheDarkAbsol, that seems to be the problem I'm running in to. Although the `focusout` event seems to work the same. Any idea on differences between `blur` and `focusout` event, should work the same?

Comment: Just to add to my answer below: focus/blur can be made to work if you make the "container" your attaching listener's to focus/blur-able (for example by sticking a tabindex on them). Please see the quicksmode blog on the subject :)

Comment: jQuery is still JavaScript so look into how it patches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Delegation is simple. Bound to the top parent. The closer, the better and faster. For example, if you want to delegate event in a specific `div`, that would be better; avoid conflict. Compare `event.target` with your target you're after, and call your callback function

```js
document.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
  
  if(event.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
      onInputBlur.apply(this, arguments);
  }

}, true);

function onInputBlur(event){
   
  // console.log(event); // event
  console.log(event.target.value);
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listeners in vanilla js pretty easily, much like you normally would. Annoyingly focus/blur behave a little different to most events (See:  http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html#link2 ) so to make this actually work you need to add a tab index to your container element.

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("blur", function(e){ 
   if(e.target.tagName == "input"){
      // do stuff
   }
},false);
```

A quick example of this in action https://jsfiddle.net/2n0v43gc/ (Edit: to see output, you need your console open (F12 on windows))

Answer (score 0):

```
function addEvent(a,b,c){
document.addEventListener(a,e=> {
      if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
      if(e.target.id==b){
      c();
      }
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
  },false);
  }
```

Use like this:

```
addEvent("click","elem",function(){});
```